# Выравнивание по нижнему краю bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как выровнять все картинки по нижнему краю, если у всех картинок разная высота?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img1.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img2.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img3.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img4.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.img-responsive {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему.

```
.row - display: table;
.col-xs-3 - display: table-cell;
```